# WPF - How to scale content in ScrollViewer properly in the full-screen mode?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How to scale content in ScrollViewer properly in the full-screen mode?
I have problem that after my app goes fullscreen, ScrollViewer still scrolling, but I need to scale it on full Window screen (Page).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.